# ActiveX controls in SysWow64 are not available to Excel

Tags: office365, activex, syswow64

In SysWow64 there are over 4 dozen controls such as ...
    comct232.ocx
    GUAGE32.OCX
    MSCOMCTL.OCX
    MSWINSCK.OCX
    VBATimer.ocx

None of these are visible or can be added to a UserForm. They can be selected using Tools/References/Browse then they do appear in the Objects Browser but that does not result in them being added to the Toolbox/Other Controls so they can't be added to a form. None of the SysWow64 ActiveX controls in SysWow64 appear and they are not available to be added to a sheet either. This problem seems to have occurred when Office 2016 Professional Plus was uninstalled and Office 365 was installed.
Has anyone seen this behavior and how was it solved?

Comment: Those are old VB6 controls. Why on earth would you want to use 90's era controls in anything modern when there are so many immensely better options available?

Comment: WAT? Immensely better options? Please enumerate! Visual Studio/.Net is a dud, left stranded in the Visual Studio sandbox with a simple error message - SecurityError. Can you tell me how to get VS2019 to allow me to access a LAN server that is not SQL but simply TCP/IP? Please explain Enlightened One.